# Can this regex involving negation and pre- and post-fixes be improved?

Tags: regex, vim

Using vim 7.4 (full version below) to examine an xxd dump, lines like:

```
00030cb0: 4845 5453 4948 4554 5349 4845 5453 4948  HETSIHETSIHETSIH
00030cc0: 4554 5349 4845 5453 4948 4554 5349 4845  ETSIHETSIHETSIHE
00030cd0: 5453 4948 4544 4d41 4554 4831 3030 3a20  TSIHEDMAETH100:
00030ce0: 5478 2062 7566 6665 7220 616c 6c6f 6361  Tx buffer alloca
00030cf0: 7465 642c 2061 6464 7220 3d20 3030 3046  ted, addr = 000F
00030d00: 4236 4639 0d0a 5453 4948 4554 5349 4845  B6F9..TSIHETSIHE
00030d10: 5453 4948 4554 5349 4845 5453 4948 4554  TSIHETSIHETSIHET
00030d20: 5349 4845 5453 4948 4554 5349 4845 5453  SIHETSIHETSIHETS
```

I'm looking for lines that don't match just a sequence of the IHETS output, 0x30cd0 - 0x30d00 inclusive above. I've got a successful regex

```
\%(  \%(\%(\%(\%(\%(I\)\?H\)\?E\)\?T\)\?S\)\?\%(IHETS\)\+\%(I\%(H\%(E\%(T\%(S\)\?\)\?\)\?\)\?\)\?\)\@<!$
```

Explanation:

- `\%(` Match as a group but don't create a backreference; needed because otherwise there are too many backreferences in the regex and vim throws an error. (Which is the impetus for asking this question.)
- `\@<!` Match (zero-width) if the preceding atom does not match
- The fact that the length of a single group of IHETS debugging output is co-prime with the 16 characters of ASCII output means I need to match partial groups as a pre- and post-fixes.

Is it possible to improve the efficiency and/or human-typing-a-lot-ness of this regex?

The other reason for asking is the log file is huge and the target lines are sparse, so each press of `n` takes quite a while.

### What I tried that did't work

I need to match any line with even a single character deviation from the IHETS group anywhere in the ASCII part. Thus checking just the beginning character or the end character in the ASCII block is not sufficient.

### Other things that won't work

I can't just delete all non-matching lines and work from there because the xxd dump is embedded in a larger log file.

### Current improvement

Thanks to @melpomene:

```
\%(  \%(\%(\%(\%(\%(I\)\?H\)\?E\)\?T\)\?S\)\?\%(IHETS\)\+\%[IHETS]\)\@18<!$
```

Unfortunately replacing the `\%(` with `\(`, while it now works given the improvement, is much slower (vim help warns about this).

### Vim version

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Included patches: 1-1689
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             -clipboard       +dialog_con      +file_in_path    +job             +menu            -mouse_sysmouse  +persistent_undo +scrollbind      -tcl             +visual          -xim
+arabic          +cmdline_compl   +diff            +find_in_path    +jumplist        +mksession       +mouse_urxvt     +postscript      +signs           +terminfo        +visualextra     -xsmp
+autocmd         +cmdline_hist    +digraphs        +float           +keymap          +modify_fname    +mouse_xterm     +printer         +smartindent     +termresponse    +viminfo         -xterm_clipboard
-balloon_eval    +cmdline_info    -dnd             +folding         +langmap         +mouse           +multi_byte      +profile         +startuptime     +textobjects     +vreplace        -xterm_save
-browse          +comments        -ebcdic          -footer          +libcall         -mouseshape      +multi_lang      -python          +statusline      +timers          +wildignore      -xpm
++builtin_terms  +conceal         +emacs_tags      +fork()          +linebreak       +mouse_dec       -mzscheme        +python3         -sun_workshop    +title           +wildmenu
+byte_offset     +cryptv          +eval            +gettext         +lispindent      +mouse_gpm       +netbeans_intg   +quickfix        +syntax          -toolbar         +windows
+channel         +cscope          +ex_extra        -hangul_input    +listcmds        -mouse_jsbterm   +packages        +reltime         +tag_binary      +user_commands   +writebackup
+cindent         +cursorbind      +extra_search    +iconv           +localmap        +mouse_netterm   +path_extra      +rightleft       +tag_old_static  +vertsplit       -X11
-clientserver    +cursorshape     +farsi           +insert_expand   -lua             +mouse_sgr       -perl            -ruby            -tag_any_white   +virtualedit     -xfontset
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?

```
/\%(  \(.\)\@=\(IHETS\|HETSI\|ETSIH\|TSIHE\|SIHET\)\2\2\1\)\@18<!$
```

The middle part is a bit tedious, but it seems to be shorter than your attempt.

The 18 in `\@18<!` is an attempt at performance optimization. It tells vim to look back at most 18 bytes in the buffer.

That said, if you're only interested in lines that don't match this pattern, it may be easier to do

```
:g/  \(.\)\@=\(IHETS\|HETSI\|ETSIH\|TSIHE\|SIHET\)\2\2\1$/d
```

up front (i.e. delete all lines that do match the pattern). No look-behind required.

---

Also,

```
\%(I\%(H\%(E\%(T\%(S\)\?\)\?\)\?\)\?\)\?
```

could have been shortened to

```
\%[IHETS]
```

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an equivalent feature for matching suffixes of a given sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on ```\@18<!```, it's in vim help as a separate item instead of ```\@[count]<!``` so I missed it.
Deleting all non-matching lines is a non-starter because the xxd dump is embedded in a larger log file.
Thanks for the tip on ```\%[IHETS]```, this is exactly what I was hoping to learn today!

Comment: _an equivalent feature for matching suffixes_ I think you mean prefixes. :-) I'll accept your answer in a couple of days it there isn't a better improvement.

Comment: Interesting! Adding the ```18``` makes a big difference in speed. I did not expect that, as the first possibility for a non-match is 18 bytes before the end of the line. Less memory allocations perhaps.

Comment: @studog `\%[IHETS]` matches prefixes of IHETS, i.e. "", "I", "IH", "IHE", "IHET", "IHETS".

Comment: Ah indeed. I was looking at where it is used, not what it's doing internally.

Comment: ```/\%(  \(.\)\@=\(IHETS\|HETSI\|ETSIH\|TSIHE\|SIHET\)\2\2\1\)\@18<!$``` works and is shorter but a little less understandable perhaps.